# Can I disable my fire simulation from risign upwards

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

So basically, I am making a scene in space where a spaceship is supposed to catch flames before exploding. However the flame is rising which is unlrealistic for a 0G enviorment.

From what I've read by hovering over the sliders in physics settings, setting the temperature in fire settings should disable its movement upwards. Problem is, the lowest value i can set is 1.0 for the maximum temp, and 0.5 for the minimum temp.

How do i tackle this problem? Can I? This is the method I used for creating my flame.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mh9tyFnzSUw

Comment: Maybe Gas > Buoyancy Density and Buoyancy Heat?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use settings like in the linked tutorial. The *Flow Type* is set to *Fire* and in the *Shader Editor* you set the *Density* in the *Principled Volume* shader to 0.

Then I would set *Gas* > *Heat* to 0 on the domain, this keeps the fire from rising. *Buoyancy Density* is making the smoke rise, so it is not so important to change it if you have set the flow object to *Fire* and the *Principled Volume* density to 0.

And if you do not want smoke and disable it in the shader anyway, you can set *Fire* > *Flame Smoke* to 0 on the smoke domain, this way it does not get calculated in the first place and makes baking significantly faster.

[image: fire settings]

On the flow object you also might want to enable *Initial Velocity* and set a value for either *Normal* or any of the axes, probably to simulate gas emanating from a pressurized inside into the vacuum.

[image: flow settings]

An alternative could be to disable *Gravity* in the *Scene Properties*, this way you can manually set *Gravity* values for each axis separately in the smoke domain.

[image: gravity settings]